# add snippets dynamically to the editor toolbar kendo

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to add snippets dynamically to the editor toolbar kendo ui
I use this code

```
@(Html.Kendo().Editor()
      .Name("textarea_question")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "span5", style = "height:10px;" })
      .Tools(tools => tools.Clear()
      .Bold().Italic().Underline()
      .Formatting()
      .JustifyLeft()
      .JustifyCenter()
      .JustifyRight()
      .JustifyFull()
      .Snippets(s => 
        {
          foreach (var item in Model.pipingText)
              {
                    s.Add(item.Name, item.Name);
              }
        })
  )
)
```

But it has error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

help me please!!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably somethings is wrong with these values that you get out of the **pipingText** collection, because rest of the code looks fine. Probably you should use the type collection instead of using **var**.

What exactly is the exception of that 500 status. Give more info about the exception.